# Why can I assign a `Function` to an `Interface` in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, interface

I am reading the [Typescript Handbook - Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html), and there is a snippet of code as the following:

```js
interface GenericIdentityFn {
    <T>(arg: T): T;
}

function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn = identity;
```

I would like to know why can I assign `identity` (which is a `Function`) to a variable with type `GenericIdentityFn` (which is an `Interface`)?

Comment: Because the interface is *of a function*? It has the callable signature, as explained [in the interface docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why not add that as an answer, seems like a good one :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir because it's a tautology explained in the official documentation? The function meets the interface because it's the interface of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an interface follows this pattern:

```
interface Callable {
  (): any
}
```

it's said that anything that implements this interface is *callable* or has a *call signature*. It's a fancy way to describe functions and methods. There are other variations of that notation:

```
interface GenericCallable<T> {
  (): T
}
```

```
interface Newable {
  new (): any
}
```

```
interface GenericNewable<T> {
  new (): T
}
```

where the ones with the `new` keyword are *newable*, which means they are called using the `new` keyword (like classes).

You can also have an interface which is *callable* and *newable* at the same time. The `Date` object built into the standard library is one of them:

```
interface DateConstructor {
    new(): Date;
    (): string;
}
```

Long story short, interfaces can also describe functions and `GenericIdentityFn` is an example of such an interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is because in Typescript, you can define function types via interfaces with a callable signature using parenthesis.

> Interfaces are capable of describing the wide range of shapes that JavaScript objects can take. In addition to describing an object with properties, interfaces are also capable of describing function types.

See the [Typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) about this feature.

In your case `identity` has the same signature as the type defined by `GenericIdentityFn` since the interface defines a callable signature that takes an argument of type `T` and returns a `T`.